# Merge two collections of the same type (which are capture of template)?

Tags: java, generics

Say I have the following two classes:

```
public class SomethingElse<A, B> {

    public List<? extends Something<A, B>> getOneList() {
        //doesn't matter
    }

    public List<? extends Something<A, B>> getAnotherList() {
        //doesn't matter
    }

}

public class Something<A, B> {
    //doesn't matter
}
```

I would like to merge the results that I get from `getOneList()` and `getAnotherList()`:

```
SomethingElse<String, Integer> somethingElse = new SomethingElse<>();
List<? extends Something<String, Integer>> oneList = somethingElse.getOneList();
List<? extends Something<String, Integer>> anotherList = somethingElse.getAnotherList();
anotherList.forEach(e -> oneList.add(e)); //<-- DOESN'T COMPILE
```

However, the compiler complains that in the `.add()` method above, it is expecting `capture of ? extends Something<String, Integer>` but I am providing... well, `capture of ? extends Something<String, Integer>`:

[image]

I feel this has something to see with type erasure but I can't figure out why, even the compiler itself is unable to produce a clear message since it's telling me I'm providing type X but it's expecting type X.

Can anyone explain me technically why the compiler doesn't like this? What are the possible wrong mixes I may be doing into the same list?

Comment: tl;dr: `anotherList` is a producer, `oneList` is a consumer.

Comment: @Turing85 thanks a lot, the duplicate question perfectly answer my question (but it didn't pop up cause I never searched for PECS terms :)

Comment: PECS: Producers Extends, Consumers Super.

Answer (score 2):

Are you really going to subclass those two classes such that you need the extends?  You could do it like this, sans the extends.  I recommend you read  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super) because using extends vs super dictates whether you can add or remove items from a list.

```
SomethingElse<String, Integer> somethingElse =
        new SomethingElse<>();
List<Something<String, Integer>> oneList =
        somethingElse.getOneList();
List<Something<String, Integer>> anotherList =
        somethingElse.getAnotherList();
    
anotherList.addAll(oneList);



class SomethingElse<A, B> {
    
    public List<Something<A, B>> getOneList() {
        return null;
    }
    
    public List<Something<A, B>> getAnotherList() {
        return null;
    }
    
}

class Something<A, B> {
    // doesn't matter
}
```

Comment: I can't modify the SomethingElse class. Though, I've tried to remove both super and extends, it works fine even if I need an unchecked cast. Any idea to avoid it?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a problem with wildcards and the contravariant and reification nature of generics.  For more info you may want to check out this article on [Covariance vs Contravariance](https://dzone.com/articles/covariance-and-contravariance).  It also talks about the get/put principle which is aka PECs.  It may give some ideas on how to handle your specific situation.